# Flutter - I need to display text, but the app doesn't

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:books_finder/books_finder.dart';

String inputText = '';
List<String> infoTitle = [];
String infoSubtitle = "";
List<String> infoAuthors = [];

class FinderBookSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const FinderBookSearch({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<FinderBookSearch> createState() => _FinderBookSearch();
}

class _FinderBookSearch extends State<FinderBookSearch> {
  void loadBookInfos() async {
    final books = await queryBooks(
      inputText,
      maxResults: 20,
      printType: PrintType.books,
      orderBy: OrderBy.relevance,
      reschemeImageLinks: true,
      langRestrict: "en",
    );
    for (var book in books) {
      var info = book.info;
      infoTitle.add(info.title);
    }
  }

  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {
                setState(() {
                  inputText = text;
                });
              },
              controller: _searchController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search...',
                // Add a clear button to the search bar
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.clear,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => _searchController.clear(),
                ),
                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => const AfterSearchScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                    loadBookInfos();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class AfterSearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AfterSearchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AfterSearchScreen> createState() => _AfterSearchScreenState();
}

class _AfterSearchScreenState extends State<AfterSearchScreen> {
  Widget a(String text) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: const ButtonStyle(),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Book Finder",
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: infoTitle.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return a(infoTitle[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That is my code. I want to display text on my app. I don't know why that code isn't work at once. It doesn't work at once. When I refresh myself in my Visual Studio Code, then it display the text.

My subject is display the elevation button without reload.
Please let me know if it works fine on your PC. Because my PC may be faulty.

Comment: `setState(() {});` is dead code here, while return on top of it, and you dont need to call setState, just make sure to have data on `infoTitle``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading the code you gave and from your question is

> I want to display text on my app. I don't know why that code isn't work at once. It doesn't work at once. When I refresh myself in my Visual Studio Code, then it display the text.

after reading this part of your code

```dart
 onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => const AfterSearchScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                    loadBookInfos();
                  },
```

I think I found your issue, because from this code you navigate to other page before the data is finish being add to list, you can move the `navigator.push` function to the `loadBookInfos`
this is the example

```dart
void loadBookInfos() async {
    final books = await queryBooks(
      inputText,
      maxResults: 20,
      printType: PrintType.books,
      orderBy: OrderBy.relevance,
      reschemeImageLinks: true,
      langRestrict: "en",
    );
    for (var book in books) {
      var info = book.info;
      infoTitle.add(info.title);
    }
      Navigator.push(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => const AfterSearchScreen(),
         ),
     );
  }
```

and on the onpressed function, remove your `navigator.push`

Comment: Is my computer weird? why not just me

Comment: can you provide your `infoTitle` list ?

Comment: I edited the question. Can you see it?

Comment: oh you say it won't work for one time, you need to refresh it for it being refresh right?

Comment: yeah that's right, but without user's touch

Comment: that basically because you call function before the data can go into list, and the result after the data show blank in screen then the data go into list. and when you refresh it it show up

Comment: but how can I refresh, when I tried to use setState() func that didn't work

Comment: let me edit my answer for a minute @Snap_Lan done, check this out

Comment: WOW are you god of Flutter? How can you fix this. WOWOWOWOWOWOW Thank You so much!

Comment: hahahha i'm not, but glad it help you, basically you need the list to be finish first to put it in a list, then you call navigate.push.

Answer (score 1):

Where is 'infoTitle' coming from? I don't see any initialization for it.

*setState(() {})* doesn't do anything here. You have to call setState if your data changed, and you want to display it on the screen.

I don't know, why it is not displayed on the screen, maybe you should try to make this widget a Stateless widget, because it doesn't need to be a Statefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- remove setState(() {});, it causes error.
- the a function should receive a String instead of index from a global variable.

  Widget a(String text) {
  return ElevatedButton(
  style: const ButtonStyle(),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: ListTile(
  title: Text(
  text,
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
  ),
  ),
  );
  }
- remove the redundant Expanded widget.

Comment: It's solved a different error, but it isn't solved my error in this question

Comment: I don't want to use setState() function too, but that Text() function isn't called(I don't know why that Text() isn't called ever.) So I decided to use setState() function to load.
```

Comment: The issue is that how to notify your widget to rebuild whenever the infoTitle variable is updated.  You could use FutureBuilder or Flutter BLOC.

Comment: Could you show me the code that you construct/update your infoTitle variable?

Comment: Please use code blocks.